# javascript replace function UTF-8 Turkish character

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, utf-8

I am developing project in ASP.NET MVC and somewhere at project, i am using JQuery load function and inside load, i am using string.replace function of javascript. 
 But when I send a word with Turkish character, it is changing the word. Word has empty space, it looks as %20 and I replace %20 with empty space  with replace function.

My word is *ÖZEL BİLGİLER* and after sending load request, it is changing to �ZEL B�LG�LER.

I am querying with that word, thus I cant get data from db. My code is below.

```
$('#mydiv').load(detail + '?Tur=' + myword.replace(/ /g, "%20"), function () {
    overlayOff();
}
```

I couldnt find any solution even I tried decodeUriComponent, replace by my own method, etc.

I need your helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to `decodeURIComponent(str);` your strings?

%20 means empty space when it's URLencoded

Comment: @toffler it is making the string �ZEL  not even show rest

Comment: what is your character encoding (html) ... have you set it to `<meta charset="UTF-8">` ?

Comment: Don't try to fix this here with regex (which will never work, since data is lost). You need to look for where encoding goes wrong and fix it ther